# ¿Cómo modifico con sed la segunda ocurrencia de un patrón?

Tags: sed

¿Cómo puedo modificar solamente la seguna ocurrencia de un patrón en `sed`?

Supongamos que tengo el texto siguiente:

```
hola Juan1 Juan2 Juan3 Juan4 adios
           ^^^^
```

Lo que querría es que se convierta en:

```
hola Juan1 Pedro2 Juan3 Juan4 adios
           ^^^^^
```

Es decir, que el segundo "Juan" se convierta en "Pedro".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para esto con `sed` y el comando `s` disponemos de la opción `/número`, donde *número* es la ocurrencia número *número* del patrón:

```
$ sed 's/Juan/Pedro/2' archivo
hola Juan1 Pedro2 Juan3 Juan4 adios
```

O usando otro ejemplo:

```
$ echo "hola hola hola" | sed 's/hola/adios/2'
hola adios hola
```

Nótese que la opción `/g` afecta a todas las ocurrencias, por lo que aplicada a nuestro ejemplo lo cambiaría todo:

```
$ echo "hola hola hola" | sed 's/hola/adios/g'
adios adios adios
```

La combinación de ambos parámetros no está definida por POSIX ([referencia](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) <sub>en inglés</sub>). Sin embargo, en GNU sed está definido de manera que `ng` reemplace todas las ocurrencias a partir de la n-ésima:

```
$ echo "hola hola hola" | sed 's/hola/adios/2g'
hola adios adios
```